# Use different MA numbers at different timeframe

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Trying to figure a way for when you click on certain timeframe, it will automatically change the EMA to a different value than what it was on.

For example

When I am on 1 Minute Timeframe, the EMA value should be 45 and when I click on
5 Minute chart, the EMA value should be 9 etc, I have gotten the below, but can't think of a way to do it. Any help be much appreciated

```
rc = input(close, title="Source")
time_warp=input.string("off", 'Cloud Timeframe', options=["off", "1m", "2m", "3m", "4m", "5m", "10m", "15m", "20m", "30m", "1h", "2h", "4h", "D", "W", "M", "Y"])
time_warp2=input.string("off", 'Trend Timeframe', options=["off", "1m", "2m", "3m", "4m", "5m", "10m", "15m", "20m", "30m", "1h", "2h", "4h", "D", "W", "M", "Y"])

// Time Warp timeframe
// Set the appropriate timeframe based on trading mode
timeframe_func() =>
    timeframe = timeframe.period 
    if time_warp == 'off'
        timeframe := timeframe.period
    else if time_warp == '1m'
        timeframe := '1'
    else if time_warp == '2m'
        timeframe := '2'
    else if time_warp == '3m'
        timeframe := '3'
    else if time_warp == '4m'
        timeframe := '4'
    else if time_warp == '5m'
        timeframe := '5'
    else if time_warp == '10m'
        timeframe := '10'
    else if time_warp == '15m'
        timeframe := '15'
    else if time_warp == '20m'
        timeframe := '20'
    else if time_warp == '30m'
        timeframe := '30'
    else if time_warp == '1h'
        timeframe := '60'
    else if time_warp == '2h'
        timeframe := '120'
    else if time_warp == '4h'
        timeframe := '240'
    else if time_warp == 'D'
        timeframe := 'D'
    else if time_warp == 'W'
        timeframe := 'W'
    else if time_warp == 'M'
        timeframe := 'M'
    else if time_warp == 'Y'
        timeframe := '12M'
    else
        timeframe := timeframe.period

riod1 = input.int(title='Fast Cloud', defval=9, minval=1)
trend_dema_value = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe_func(), ta.ema(src, Period1)[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0], gaps=barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off)
ZEMA1 = plot(trend_dema_value, color=color.new(#089c84, 100), linewidth=1, title='Fast Cloud')

Period2 = input.int(title='Pivot Cloud', defval=21, minval=1)
trend_dema_value2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe_func(), 2 * ta.ema(src, Period2)[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0], gaps=barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off)
ZEMA2 = plot(trend_dema_value2, color=color.new(color.red, 100), linewidth=1, title='Pivot Cloud')
```

EMA value to change to another on different timeframes

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use build in helper function for the MA/EMA indicators in Pine script.   like th (ta.ema(close,21))